# Is calculation allowed in the draw function

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an app in which I want to scale my drawing. So I am multiplying dimensions by a factor I call unitDim.
So in my draw function I have a function like this:

```
for  i in 2..<700 {
            context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(coordinateXOrigin + Float(i + 1) * unitDim), y: CGFloat(coordinateYOriginPlusaxisLength - MSCArrayOriginal[i])))
        }
```

But I think I read somewhere that an app will be rejected if calculations like this occur within the draw function. On the other hand, I can think of no other way of achieving this.

Comment: is it the `drawInContext` you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm… do you happen to remember where you read that?  It makes no sense to me that an app would not be allowed to perform mathematical calculations in its drawing methods.

Now, if you try to cram all of that into *one line*, you might get errors from the Swift compiler about `Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time`, but if you break it into a handful of lines you should be fine.